# Eqnarray cannot handle lines starting with a bracket

Tags: math-mode, equations, arrays

I just noticed this, but it seem obvious. A construct like this

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
   a & = & b \\
   [c]_d & = & \ldots
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
```

Does not compile because latex thinks the opening bracket is part of a `\\[<length>]` expression. Granted, I could replace it by `\left[`, but is there a less cluttering way of having latex not treat the bracketed content as a row separation length?

Comment: Try `{}[c]_d` to get past it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Good idea. It works, although it's also not pretty.

Comment: `amsmath` has avoided this problem in `align` et al. by requiring that an optional length expression not be separated from the `\\ ` by a space.  however, `amsmath` does not recognize (but deprecates the use of) `eqnarray` because of its flawed handling of space around signs of relation.

Answer (score 2):

As the OP properly diagnoses, the brackets are mistakenly taken as an argument to the preceding `\\`.  The solution is to remove that interpretation by placing a `{}` following the `\\` (or prior to the `[c]`).

While it may not seem pretty, it is the proper way to remove the confusion from the syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}{rCl}
   a & = & b \\{}
   [c]_d & = & \ldots
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd prefer ``\\\relax`, but it's not so important.

Comment: @egreg I'll make a mental note of that.